# Rare behaviour in command line arguments

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program in cpp using maps...

My goal is to allow * alone when we pass via comand line argument

And i have to restrict the characters coming along with * (ie)*abc and abc*

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    prinf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    char str[256] = "";
    int length;
    strcpy(str,argv[1]);
    length = strlen(str);       
    if((str[0] = '*' )&& (length == 1))
        printf("success\n");
    else
        printf("failure");
    return 0;

}
```

when i run this program ,getting the following output

```
 $ ./exec *
   $ 1
   $ failure
```

argv[1] = 1(printing 1 instead of *)

failure because of not getting * as input argument,it results in failure.

Could someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You know that "cpp` is not "c", right?

Comment: what's `length` anyway?

Comment: What is `length`? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Complete with `#include` files.

Comment: This program does not compile:  syntax errors, lacking #includes, at least.  Why not get the parts working that you can, rather than having us solve things you already know how to fix yourself?  Or, as the poster above said:  [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Items on the command line are processed by the shell.

In the shell, the `*` performs a `glob` operation

In general, a `glob` operator, when standing alone, will result in a list of all the files in the current directory.

Comment: And the fix is to run the program as: `./prog '*'` or `./prog "*"` or `./prog \*`.  I'd use the first.

Answer (score 3):

The character `*` has a special meaning in most shells. Your shell expands it to the files in the current directory resulting in a completely different arguments than the one you intended.

To avoid this, you can do:

```
 $ ./exec "*"
```

or

```
 $ ./exec '*'
```

---

If your shell is bash, then you can also turn off the globbing expansion with:

```
$ set -o noglob
```

or

```
$ set -f
```

but I would suggest the former options (above) as it's "minimal" and doesn't affect your shell's default behaviour otherwise.